# Is HashMap.put for String keys generally a bottleneck? How do I speed it up?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm writing a [Random Indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_indexing) implementation in Java, which needs to process large corpora and somehow store individual tokens' context and index vectors. A HashMap seemed natural (String -> Token object), but when running Xprof it seems like a disproportionate large portion of the processing goes to adding the token to the HashMap.

Am I reading the output correctly? Why is this, and is there some way for me to speed things up?

```
Flat profile of 16.18 secs (606 total ticks): main
  Interpreted + native   Method                        
  6.9%     0  +    42    java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes
  5.0%     0  +    30    java.lang.Object.getClass
  1.8%    11  +     0    java.lang.String.toLowerCase
  1.5%     9  +     0    java.util.HashMap.resize
  1.3%     8  +     0    opennlp.tools.tokenize.AbstractTokenizer.tokenize
  1.3%     0  +     8    java.util.zip.ZipFile.read
  1.2%     0  +     7    java.util.zip.ZipFile.open
  0.8%     5  +     0    java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange
  0.5%     0  +     3    java.io.FileInputStream.available
  0.3%     2  +     0    java.util.HashMap.put
  0.3%     0  +     2    sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapLong
  0.3%     2  +     0    java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1.toLowerCase
  0.3%     2  +     0    java.util.ArrayList.grow
  0.3%     2  +     0    semanticspace.SparseVector.get
  0.3%     2  +     0    java.lang.CharacterData.of
  0.2%     1  +     0    java.util.HashMap.createEntry
  0.2%     1  +     0    java.util.Arrays.copyOf
  0.2%     1  +     0    java.lang.Integer.valueOf
  0.2%     1  +     0    java.lang.Integer.toString
  0.2%     1  +     0    sun.misc.JarIndex.addToList
  0.2%     1  +     0    java.util.ArrayList.toArray
  0.2%     1  +     0    java.net.URL.toString
  0.2%     1  +     0    semanticspace.SparseVector.add
  0.2%     1  +     0    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
  0.2%     1  +     0    java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1
 26.2%    65  +    94    Total interpreted (including elided)

     Compiled + native   Method                        
 36.5%   217  +     4    java.util.HashMap.put
 24.3%   133  +    14    semanticspace.SparseVector.add
  2.6%    15  +     1    semanticspace.RandomIndexing.getToken
  1.3%     8  +     0    java.lang.String.toLowerCase
  1.3%     8  +     0    semanticspace.RandomIndexing.read
  0.5%     0  +     3    java.util.HashMap.newKeyIterator
  0.2%     0  +     1    semanticspace.SparseVector.get
  0.2%     1  +     0    java.util.HashMap.containsKey
 66.8%   382  +    23    Total compiled

         Stub + native   Method                        
  6.9%     0  +    42    java.lang.System.arraycopy
  6.9%     0  +    42    Total stub


Flat profile of 0.00 secs (1 total ticks): DestroyJavaVM

  Thread-local ticks:
100.0%     1             Blocked (of total)


Flat profile of 16.17 secs (608 total ticks): Monitor Ctrl-Break

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
 98.2%     0  +   597    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept
  1.0%     0  +     6    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.initProto
  0.7%     0  +     4    java.net.NetworkInterface.getAll
  0.2%     0  +     1    java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load
100.0%     0  +   608    Total interpreted


Global summary of 16.33 seconds:
100.0%  1326             Received ticks
 53.2%   706             Received GC ticks
  6.8%    90             Compilation
  0.1%     1             Other VM operations
```

Comment: Maybe your `String` input contains a very large value and the `hashCode` function becomes slower than the others.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Xprof, but you can try profiling with visualvm, and see how many times it calls HashMap.put, how long it takes each time and in total. And also it might have a different picture of where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much information in your question to make a proper analysis, but based on what I can see you're simply reading a file and putting the words into a HashMap.

Given the fact that that is the only thing the program does, one shouldn't be at all surprised that it spends most of its time reading the file and updating the HashMap.